# Promtail/ Loki - Empty results, no matching label

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

Im trying to send the following logs to loki using promtail, here is an example of the log line `2023-04-13 09:09:49,762 | 2a81c3e799f446c5800c954c38a67c8c | INFO | test | {'foo':'bar'}`

My promtail config is as follows:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: 'http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: scrape_django
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: django_logs
          __path__: /var/log/app.log
    pipeline_stages:
      - regex:
          expression: '(?P<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) \| (?P<request_id>[a-fA-F0-9]{32}) \| (?P<level>\w+) \| (?P<value>\w+) \| (?P<data>\{.*\})'
      - timestamp:
          source: time
          location: Asia/Kolkata
          format: '2006-01-02 15:04:05,000'
      - labels:
          level:
```

when im trying to access the label using job='django_logs', im getting the following error:

```
Empty results, no matching label for {job="django_logs"}
```

The pipeline stages using `--inspect` gives me the following output:

```
{stages.Entry}.Extracted["level"]:
    +: INFO
{stages.Entry}.Extracted["request_id"]:
    +: 2a81c3e799f446c5800c954c38a67c8c
{stages.Entry}.Extracted["time"]:
    +: 2023-04-13 09:09:49,76
{stages.Entry}.Extracted["value"]:
    +: test
[inspect: labels stage]: 
{stages.Entry}.Entry.Labels:
    -: {filename="/var/log/app.log", job="django_logs"}
    +: {filename="/var/log/app.log", job="django_logs", level="INFO"}
{stages.Entry}.Extracted["data"]:
    +: {'foo':'bar's}
```

If I remove the timestamp stage it is working

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution here: https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/5928.

Made changes to my loki config. My logs were old, therefore not appearing.

```
ingester:
  max_chunk_age: 72h (default is 2h)
```